# Libfaketime Linux 3.1.0?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to create a software like RunAsDate for Linux. I'm working on Linux 3.1.0, and libfaketime doesn't work.
Can anyone help me with this?
I think I have the latest version.

Here is the problem:

```
$ ./faketime 'last friday 5 pm' /bin/date
date: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1: undefined symbol: dlsym
Error: Timestamp to fake not recognized, please re-try with a different timestamp.
```

I ran `sudo make install`, then linked /usr/local/lib/faketime to /usr/lib/faketime.

EDIT: in response to hotchl's answer, and here is the (same) output:

```
$ tar paxvf libfaketime-0.8.1.tar.gz
libfaketime-0.8.1/
libfaketime-0.8.1/test/
libfaketime-0.8.1/test/Makefile
libfaketime-0.8.1/test/timetest.c
libfaketime-0.8.1/test/test.sh
libfaketime-0.8.1/README
libfaketime-0.8.1/Makefile
libfaketime-0.8.1/man/
libfaketime-0.8.1/man/Makefile
libfaketime-0.8.1/man/faketime.1
libfaketime-0.8.1/src/
libfaketime-0.8.1/src/Makefile
libfaketime-0.8.1/src/faketime
libfaketime-0.8.1/src/faketime.c
libfaketime-0.8.1/meta/
libfaketime-0.8.1/meta/Makefile
libfaketime-0.8.1/meta/Changelog
libfaketime-0.8.1/meta/COPYING
$ cd libfaketime-0.8.1/src
$ make
gcc -o faketime.o -c -std=gnu99 -Wall -DFAKE_STAT -DFAKE_INTERNAL_CALLS -fPIC  faketime.c
gcc -o libfaketime.so.1 -Wl,-soname,libfaketime.so.1 -shared -ldl -lm -lpthread faketime.o
gcc -o faketimeMT.o -c -std=gnu99 -Wall -DFAKE_STAT -DFAKE_INTERNAL_CALLS -fPIC -DPTHREAD -DPTHREAD_SINGLETHREADED_TIME faketime.c
gcc -o libfaketimeMT.so.1 -Wl,-soname,libfaketimeMT.so.1 -shared -ldl -lm -lpthread faketimeMT.o
$ LD_PRELOAD=`pwd`/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="-15d" /bin/date
/bin/date: symbol lookup error: ./libfaketime.so.1: undefined symbol: dlsym
```

Comment: What isn't working about libfaketime?

Comment: Sorry about that! I edited the post.

Comment: Not enough information exception. Please reboot question :)

Comment: Hmmm, I assume you are using the source tarball, but the error says `/usr/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1` which is somewhere different on your system. I suggest trying an easy test format first, like `FAKETIME="-1d"` or such.

Comment: I did, and it still didn't work. (I edited my post. Is that what you wanted?)

Comment: Hmm, just downloaded this stuff -- I think you first have to build it, do `cd src; make` and then see if you have the library there.

Comment: Is your /bin/date a dynamically linked executable? Does ldd /bin/date show dependencies to shared libraries? Also, does it link to libdl.so.2? If not, try adding /lib/libdl.so.2 to LD_PRELOAD path.

Comment: If you want, you can edit your answer, and I'll give you the "correct answer" bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your /bin/date a dynamically linked executable? Does ldd /bin/date show dependencies to shared libraries? Also, does it link to libdl.so.2?

If it is dynamically linked but does not link to libdl.so.2., add /lib/libdl.so.2 to LD_PRELOAD path.

Comment: Sorry for not giving the "correct answer" before! I can confirm this works :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what works:

```
$ tar paxvf libfaketime-0.8.1.tar.gz
libfaketime-0.8.1/
libfaketime-0.8.1/test/
libfaketime-0.8.1/test/Makefile
libfaketime-0.8.1/test/timetest.c
libfaketime-0.8.1/test/test.sh
libfaketime-0.8.1/README
libfaketime-0.8.1/Makefile
libfaketime-0.8.1/man/
libfaketime-0.8.1/man/Makefile
libfaketime-0.8.1/man/faketime.1
libfaketime-0.8.1/src/
libfaketime-0.8.1/src/Makefile
libfaketime-0.8.1/src/faketime
libfaketime-0.8.1/src/faketime.c
libfaketime-0.8.1/meta/
libfaketime-0.8.1/meta/Makefile
libfaketime-0.8.1/meta/Changelog
libfaketime-0.8.1/meta/COPYING
$ cd libfaketime-0.8.1/src
$ make
gcc -o faketime.o -c -std=gnu99 -Wall -DFAKE_STAT -DFAKE_INTERNAL_CALLS -fPIC  faketime.c
gcc -o libfaketime.so.1 -Wl,-soname,libfaketime.so.1 -shared -ldl -lm -lpthread faketime.o
gcc -o faketimeMT.o -c -std=gnu99 -Wall -DFAKE_STAT -DFAKE_INTERNAL_CALLS -fPIC -DPTHREAD -DPTHREAD_SINGLETHREADED_TIME faketime.c
gcc -o libfaketimeMT.so.1 -Wl,-soname,libfaketimeMT.so.1 -shared -ldl -lm -lpthread faketimeMT.o
$ LD_PRELOAD=`pwd`/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="-15d" /bin/date
Sat Nov  5 06:10:46 CET 2011
```

The script `faketime` in `src` somehow didn't work ootb for me, but it's 6 am so maybe I was just too tired ;-) It cointains a lot of comments that refer to the documentation, so I guess you can make it work by looking there.

Comment: Ok this is odd, it looks like a missing `-ldl`, but `-ldl` is clearly set on compilation.